# MS Access 2010 Report Grouping-Sorting issue

Tags: sorting, ms-access, report

I Have an app that creates a report from a query (nothing special in that right?).

The query runs perfectly and everytihng is in the order I require for my report.

However when I group records in the report the sort order is mucked up.  Looking at the report groups options I can only sort groups in ascending or descending order. I don't want either.

I don't want the report group to sort in any order other the sort order within the query i.e.

**Bin: 100**

Shelf: 1

Cat: Film

Item: First item

**Bin: 101**

Shelf: 1

Cat: Film

Item: Second item

**Bin: 102**

Shelf: 2

Cat: Film

Item: Third Item

**Bin: 103**

Shelf: 3

Cat: Roll

Item: Roll One

**Bin: 104**

Shelf: 1

Cat: Roll

Item: Roll number two

I want all items to display in Bin order by grouped by Shelf then Cat.  However because of a-z or z-a in grouping it stuffs up the bin sorting order as per below.

**Bin: 100**

Shelf: 1

Cat: Film

Item: First item

**Bin: 101**

Shelf: 1

Cat: Film

Item: Second item

**Bin: 102**

Shelf: 2

Cat: Film

Item: Third Item

**Bin: 104**

Shelf: 1

Cat: Roll

Item: Roll number two

**Bin: 103**

Shelf: 3

Cat: Roll

Item: Roll One

Anyone have any clues on how I can get around this limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access Reports ignore the query sort order.

You set the sort order in the report.

By definition it does not make sense to sort a report group by anything other than itself.

However you do not need to show the grouping field/expression, you are welcome to show whatever field you wish in the report header.

In your case you can group by the criteria you use to sort your query.

Comment: Sounds like I'm going to have restructure my data to get what I want. Removed all sorting in the query and duplicated in the report.  It still doesn't work.  thanks anyway.